# Separating Multiple Lines in Cell while Keeping Same Row Title

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Google Sheets to dynamically import election results from a RSS/XML file, but I'm having trouble separating information in the same cell.

Basically, the candidates and their results are all listed on separate lines in the same cell in a row that has the race title. I'm looking to break those candidates out, so they are on their own row, and the race title is copied for each row.

In one sheet, I use this formula to bring in the data: `=IMPORTFEED("https://mielections.us/election/results/RSS/2020PRI_MI_CENR_SUMMARY.rss","","",250)`

In another, I use these formulas to move over the data I want:
Column A
`=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oEQMbB_mm55ssfz3Qf3fGQBpkpL2FUljQa0iqU6kEjs/edit#gid=0","Sheet1!A1:A250")`
Column B `=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oEQMbB_mm55ssfz3Qf3fGQBpkpL2FUljQa0iqU6kEjs/edit#gid=0","Sheet1!D1:D250")`

In a third column, I tried this, which separates the candidates in the cell to a new column: `=SPLIT(B1,char(10))` However, I want each candidate to go to a new row and copy the race title.

I also tried this: `=FLATTEN(Sheet2!A1:O250)` However, it leaves a lot of blank rows and doesn't copy the race titles with each candidate.

Here's a copy of the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oEQMbB_mm55ssfz3Qf3fGQBpkpL2FUljQa0iqU6kEjs/edit?usp=sharing

Any idea how I can get something like this?

Race 1   Candidate 1

Race 2   Candidate 1

Race 2   Candidate 2

Comment: Please allow access to everyone with a [the  link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10DD3ys6F77PFNzEa7fW5xa9IOUs48W0j5OEdAl1nk5Y/edit) in this spreadsheet to be able to view the `Importrange` output, otherwise the sheet2 and Sheet3 is empty.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that when I copied over the spreadsheet; it's fixed now. It's incredible what's possible with Google Sheets; I'm just a bit stuck reformatting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use Google Apps Script

To address the issue in this post, I recommend using a script through Google Apps Script since the process is quite complex. For my setup, I used a Google Sheet file with two tabs, `Data` and `Output`.

For the `Data` tab, I used the same `IMPORTFEED()` formula you used to get the data from the given URL.

```
=IMPORTFEED("https://mielections.us/election/results/RSS/2020PRI_MI_CENR_SUMMARY.rss","",true,250)
```

[image]

Afterwards, you may use this script as the base of your script:

```
function extractData() {
  var ssData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var lr = ssData.getLastRow();
  var ssOut = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Output");
  var count = 1;
  var out = []
  for (i = 2; i <= lr; i++) {
    var data = ssData.getRange(i, 4, 1, 1).getValues().toString().trim().split("\n");
    var length = data.length;
    for (j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      count++;
      var populate = (ssData.getRange(i,1,lr,1).getValue());
      out.push([populate,data[j]]);
    }
  }
  ssOut.getRange(2,1,count-1,2).setValues(out);
}
```

This script uses a nested `for` loop to extract and rearrange the data from the `Data` tab to the `Output` tab. The script first counts the number of lines there are in the cells under the `Summary` column. Afterwards, the script splits the cells into multiple rows using the `.split()` function with the `\n` (new line) set as the delimiter. After that, the script will then duplicate the data under the `title` column based on the number of lines in the `summary` cells. After the data has been arranged, the script will then place the new data to the `Output` tab.

### Output

After the script is done running, the `Output` tab should look like this:
[image]

Comment: If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks, that seems more logical and less messy than multiple formulas. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything special I need to do in Google Apps Script? I used the menu in the spreadsheet and entered the function, but the execution seems to fail.

Comment: `I used the menu in the spreadsheet and entered the function` Do you mean `Extensions > Apps Script`? That is correct. Have you renamed the sheet names in the script? For my script I used the `Data` to represent the sheet wherein the `importfeed` function is used and I used the `Output` to represent the blank sheet wherein the rearranged data will be placed. When running, an authorization screen should pop up to ask for your permission to access the sheet. You need to allow it. If this does not fix your current issue `the execution seems to fail`, may I ask what the error message is?

Comment: It appears to be a permissions issue with the Google account I'm using, which has also been used for some Apps Script. I tried another, granted the permissions requested, and it worked fine. Thanks again.